# CollectionView.MoveCurrentTo sets Current item to null

Tags: c#, collectionview

I'm trying to set the current Item in a CollectionView using the MoveCurrentTo method but the result is that the collectionView:s current item is set to null.

My collectionViewSource.source is a dictionary. What I am trying to do is to add a new item to my collection and then set the current item in the view to the new item but I cant get it to work.

Could anyone explain why this does not work?

```
 Customers customers = null;

  customers = new Customers();
  customers.Fill();

  CustomerCollectionView = new CollectionViewSource();
  CustomerCollectionView.Source = customers.Values;

  Customer customerItem = new Customer();
  customers.Add(customerItem);
  CustomerCollectionView.View.MoveCurrentTo(customerItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

The collection exposed by customers.Values probably does no support INotifyCollectionChanged. Using an ObservableDictionary implementation would likely solve your problem.